# Django: ModelViewSet update() returns TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' during image upload

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I want to upload an image from the user's profile page. The URL from where I am uploading the image is the **Detail** page. That's why it has the user ID at the end of the URL. But, when I make a PATCH request after adding the image in Postman, Django returns this error:

```
TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

This is my URL:
[image: postman]

Since, I need to update a profile from it's detail page, the ID is present in the URL. If I remove the ID it says:

`{"detail": "Method \"PATCH\" not allowed."}`

This is my `update()`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return CustomUser.objects.all().filter(email = self.request.user)

def update(self, request):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(instance = self.request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
        return Response({
                'status': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                'message': 'Profile updated successfully'
            }, serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So how do I upload an image as someone who updates profile picture from the profile page? Assuming that the profile page is a DETAIL or RETRIEVE view.

Comment: replace `def update(self, request)` with `de fupdate(self, request, pk)`. The `pk` is the item you need to update.

Comment: Then it says: `TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partial'`. Even if the `partial=True` argument is present or not!

Answer (score 1):

Follow up for : Then it says: TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partial'. Even if the partial=True argument is present or not!

Try self.partial = True.

(Apologies I cannot comment yet due to my low rep score)